# The space of finite signed measures and duality

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measure space and $\mathcal{X}$ be a linear space of measurable functions from $X$ into the real numbers. So $\mathcal{X}$ could for instance be an $L_p$ space. Now in a paper that I am reading they are stating that we can now find a (topological) dual space $\mathcal{X}^*$ of finite signed measures $\mu$ on $(X, \mathcal{A})$ with $\int_X |f|d|\mu|<\infty$ for all $f\in\mathcal{X}$, such that the pairing
$$ \langle \mu, f\rangle := \int_X f d\mu$$
is well defined.

1.) So this essentially means that the space of all finite signed measures has to be the topological dual of spaces of real-valued measurable functions. Is this correct? If so where can I find a proof of that?

2.) If I take the $\mathcal{X}=L_p(X, \mathcal{A}, \nu)$ for some positive measure $\nu$, then its topological dual is the space $L_q(X, \mathcal{A}, \nu)$ with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and not some space of (signed) measures. So how does that fit into the above setting?

Comment: From your phrasing, it looks like the authors are only saying that every continuous linear functional on $\mathcal X$ can be described as integration against a signed measure, and are not saying that every signed measure defines via integration a continuous linear functional on $\mathcal X$.

Comment: thanks for your commment. What exactly does that imply? Also if the space of finite signed measures is the topological dual space, then these signed measures should be the continuous linear functionals on $\mathcal{A}$ and not just describe them, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are referring to is a version of the [Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem). The space of continuous compactly supported functions has these measures as their dual.

To your second question, the theorem implies that every functional given a fixed measure, is essentially integrating with a 'density' from $L^q$ when $1\leq p< \infty$. You can look at [Dual Lp spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Dual_spaces) and the references it links to. Both facts should be in any sufficiently comprehensive functional analysis book.

Comment: thanks for your answer! So are real valued measurable functions automatically continuous? Another question: Are these functions in my question compactly supported though?

Comment: Also which form of the riesz markov kakutani theorem is being used here? the first one in the wiki article only gives us a positive measure and the second version in the article only holds for functions that vanish at infinity

Comment: Real valued measurable functions are not generally continuous, but continuous functions are dense in $L^p$ for Radon measures, which are the measures one gets from the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation. It is also mentioned in the linked page, that there is no uniqueness of the measure giving a functional if you do not assume regularity of the measure.

Comment: @guest1 To your second comment, the second version gives you what you need since vanishing at infinity also holds for compactly supported functions. Any general $L^p$ function can be approximated by compactly supported functions in the $L^p$ norm. A continuous functional is uniquely determined by its values on a dense subset.